# Deleted a user in rails but the session still exists--how to clear this too?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I had created several test users in my rails app to test the login.  They were automatically logged in by setting a session.

Once I was satisfied with the user login, I went into the rails console and deleted the users with 
`User.last.delete`

However, now when I try to load localhost:3000, my browser is still looking for user number 14, whom I just deleted.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StaticPagesController#home

Couldn't find User with id=14

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `current_user'
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb___2558135612319095530_70269927858560'

Request

Parameters:

None
```

Even restarting the server and completely clearing the database with in `rake db:reset`didn't help---shouldn't this destroy whatever session problem is telling my app look for id=14?

Comment: You deleted the users but it looks like the session still refers to it. You should delete the cookies for localhost. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cookies, that's what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing cookies does not help, you can try to use controller responsible for creating sessions.
You sholud have method, which destroys session, for example:

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged out'
end
```

Add some route to it and then simply navigate in browser to

```
localhost:3000/logout
```